# SingleTon GCD method invoking?

Tags: ios, singleton, grand-central-dispatch

Ok this is a conceptual question.
I got a singleton class

```
+(instancetype)gameObjectSingleTon{
static GameObject *game = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{

    if(myBOOL){
        NSLog(@"Get Defaut settings!");
    }
    else {
        game = [[GameObject alloc]init];
        game.difficultyLevel = @"1";

    }
});

return game;
```

}
Here game is self. Now whenever i invoke this method to get the singleton object, value of `MyBOOL` might change and does the code inside the GCD snippet even invoke? I am confused about this. If i already have an object of this class in memory and again calling it or creating another instance using this singleton, doesnt the code inside the snippet run?

Answer (score 0):

After going through the documentation for the nth time and following the correct GCD pattern , came to the conclusion that, As the object invokes a static object of itself, initialisation is done for only 1 time per lifetime of the application.
We can change the values of the static object with getter setter or property here, But anything inside the GCD block WONT be invoked IF that invocation is already done before lifetime of the app cycle.